# How to improve method structure to reduce params?

Tags: php, laravel, refactoring, code-readability

In many methods in the service classes I am repeating the code like this:

```
$model->addEvent($provider->id, 'installing', 'username', 'add', 'Description of event');

$this->worker->uploadFile($provider->id, 'root', $file);
```

Many different `$model` will have `addEvent()` which is done via trait.

How can I refactor those two lines into a method with readable/memorable parameters?

I have tried the following:

```
public function deploy($model, $providerId, $status, $user, $action, $file, $description = null)
{
   $model->addEvent($providerId, $status, $user, $action, $description);

   $this->serverWorker->uploadFile($providerId, $user, $file);
}
```

What I don't like about this method that there is too many params.

Usage:

Eg 1. `deploy($site, 1, 'In Queue', 'root', 'create', $file, 'Installing Site domain.com')`

Eg 2. `deploy($rule, 1, 'In Queue', 'root', 'update', $file, 'Updating Rule')`

Eg 2. `deploy($something, 1, 'In Queue', 'root', 'delete', $file)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping the common configurations into small reusable classes like so:

```
public function deploy($model, FileDeployTarget $target, $description = null)
{
   $model->addEvent($target->providerId, $target->status, $target->user, $target->action, $description);

   $this->serverWorker->uploadFile($target->providerId, $target->user, $target->file);
}
```

And somewhere else:

```
class UpdateInQueue extends FileDeployTarget {
    public $status = 'In Queue';
    public $action = 'update';
}
```

FileDeployTarget and descendants would handle all extra parameters in their constructors.

Comment: Can you provide example of `deploy()` usage passing to $target parm?

Comment: Something like `deploy($rule, new UpdateInQueue($file), "Updating Rule")`